# How to configure API endpoint to receive file from ember-uploader component

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ember.js

I'm trying to figure out how to use [ember-uploader](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader), I have the following component (like the one in the README)

```js
export default EmberUploader.FileField.extend({
  filesDidChange: function(files) {
    const uploader = EmberUploader.Uploader.create({
      url: (ENV.APP.API_HOST || '') + '/api/v1/images/',
    });
    console.log(uploader);

    if (!Ember.isEmpty(files)) {
      var photo = files[0];
      console.log(photo);

      uploader.upload(photo)
        .then(data => {
          // Handle success
          console.log("Success uploading file");
          console.log(data);
        }, error => {
          // Handle failure
          console.log("ERROR uploading file");
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

The express API endpoint is listening for a POST request.

```js
var saveImage = (req, res, next) => {
    let body = req.body;
    res.json({
      data: body
    });
};
```

But the `body` is empty after the request is done. I really don't know how to implement the API endpoint in order to get the file, I tried to see the `req` object and it doesn't contains the file.

Debugging it, After select a file using the component I get the following info in the console.

[image: js console]

Seems that the API endpoint works because I get the following output:

```
POST /api/v1/images/ 200 27.284 ms - 11
```

But I can't get the file.

Comment: Could you help me? Any ideas?

Comment: Please move your solution to an individual answer instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUTION

> In Express 4, req.files is no longer available on the req object by
>   default. To access uploaded files on the req.files object, use a
>   multipart-handling middleware like busboy, multer, formidable,
>   multiparty, connect-multiparty, or pez.

Following this [blog](http://shiya.io/simple-file-upload-with-express-js-and-formidable-in-node-js/), the code below was added to the API and the ember-uploader code posted in the question worked as expected.

```js
import formidable from 'formidable';

var saveImage = (req, res, next) => {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req);

    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
        file.path = __dirname + '/tmp/' + file.name;
    });

    form.on('file', function (name, file){
        res.json({
            data: file.name
        });           
    });
};
```